# parse a url with the command line only

Tags: awk, sed

I have a csv file looking like this:

```
id,author,url
1,bob,http://mywebsite.com/path/to/content
2,john,https://anotherwebsite.com/path/to/some/other/content
3,alice,http://www.somewebsite.com/path/to/content
```

And I'd like to turn it into:

```
id,author,url
1,bob,mywebsite.com
2,john,anotherwebsite.com
3,alice,somewebsite.com
```

I know this could be done easily with javascript or python but I am trying to understand how `awk` and `sed` work. Is there a way to do this easily with command line tools only?

Many thanks

Comment: there are lots of similar questions in SO which ask parsing url with re. the sincere answer is, please don't. if you want to learn these two tools, you need to find something properer. url is not something suitable for re.

Comment: You want `www.somewebsite.com` converted to `somewebsite.com`. Is `www` the only prefix you want to strip? What about the general case of `foo.somewebsite.com`, e.g. `www.google.com` vs `drive.google.com` vs `calendar.google.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{split($3,a,"/");$0=$1","$2","a[3]}1' file
id,author,url
1,bob,mywebsite.com
2,john,anotherwebsite.com
3,alice,www.somewebsite.com
```

Split the line using `,`
Then for all except first line `NR>1`, split filed `$3`, recreate the line.
`1`print all

---

Also remove `www.`

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{split($3,a,"/");sub(/^www./,"",a[3]);$0=$1","$2","a[3]}1'
id,author,url
1,bob,mywebsite.com
2,john,anotherwebsite.com
3,alice,somewebsite.com
```

Comment: This  `sub(/^www./,"",a[3])` removes `www.` from URL if it have it in the start.  Se my updated post.

Comment: If you want to strip all suffixes, not just `www.`, you might want: `awk -F'[,/]+' 'NR>1{match($4,/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/); $0=$1","$2","substr($4,RSTART,RLENGTH)}1' file`

Comment: @EdMorton Not a good solution.  This will change  `site.com.br` to `com.br`

Comment: That's the intent so that, for example, `drive.google.com` is reduced to `google.com` just like `www.google.com` would be. Why is that not a good solution? I'd THINK that'd be desirable...

Comment: @EdMorton As I wrote, there are many sites using double country extension that will suffer from this.  Look at these two: `www.time.co.uk` and `time.co.uk`.  My solution would give `time.co.uk` and `time.co.uk`, yours give `time.co.uk` and `co.uk`.  The last will then not give a useful domain name.

Comment: Good point but I think a working solution wouldn't leave `drive.google.com` as-is. idk what the answer is, something for the OP to consider!